# Upgrade from ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 not possible

Tags: upgrade

Each time I tried to upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10 the upgrade window disappears with the message "the old system status will be set."
The headline of the window displays:

> The system will be upgraded to version 19.10. After 193 files were downloaded and the first line tells "upgrade will be prepared.

After about 3 seconds the arrow in the first line is replaced by a red cycle with a white x and the upgrade window disappears immediately.
Rem: the upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04 some month ago was successful.

There is an additional information in the `ubuntu-software` app:

> The download or upgrade is not possible: failed to refresh cache: E: http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ ubuntu disco-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 icons is not (yet) available (could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partialat.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_disco-updates_main_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz - open (13: permission denied) [IP:83.164.133.196.80})

I don't know if this message belongs to the system upgrade because the download of the 193 upgrade-files was successful.

Does anyone know the reason and having a solution?
Thanks

errors when doing "sudo apt-get update":

Rem: caused by limited number of links I replaced http with xxxx

```
chefadmin@Mizzi:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] Passwort für chefadmin: 

-Begin of output

OK:1 xxxx://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease

Holen:2 xxxx://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97,5 kB]                             

OK:3 xxxx://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                  
...

Fehl:10 xxxx://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons

  Datei /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/at.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_disco-updates_main_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz konnte nicht geöffnet werden. - open (13: Keine Berechtigung) [IP: 83.164.133.196 80]
...

Fehl:33 xxxx://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata

  Datei /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/at.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_disco-backports_main_cnf_Commands-amd64.xz konnte nicht geöffnet werden. - open (13: Keine Berechtigung) [IP: 83.164.133.196 80]
...

Fehl:55 xxxx://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons

  Datei /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_disco-security_main_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz konnte nicht geöffnet werden. - open (13: Keine Berechtigung) [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
...

Es wurden 284 kB in 4 s geholt (67,2 kB/s).

Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig

E: Fehlschlag beim Holen von xxx://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar Datei /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/at.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_disco-updates_main_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz konnte nicht geöffnet werden. - open (13: Keine Berechtigung) [IP: 83.164.133.196 80]

E: Fehlschlag beim Holen von xxxx://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-backports/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 Datei /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/at.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_disco-backports_main_cnf_Commands-amd64.xz konnte nicht geöffnet werden. - open (13: Keine Berechtigung) [IP: 83.164.133.196 80]

E: Fehlschlag beim Holen von xxxx://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-security/main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar Datei /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_disco-security_main_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz konnte nicht geöffnet werden. - open (13: Keine Berechtigung) [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]

E: Einige Indexdateien konnten nicht heruntergeladen werden. Sie wurden ignoriert oder alte an ihrer Stelle benutzt.
```

-End of output

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` manually in the terminal and add output to the question.

Comment: Hi, I added the error-output wehn doing "sudo apt-get ubuntu". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to upgrade in a more Debian way, even though it's not a recommended method:

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/disco/eoan/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Once the upgrade process is done and after reboot you may use a tool like "*Y PPA Manager*" to upgrade your other repositories from **Disco** to **Eoan**.

Comment: Is your desktop still alive? I have fear to follow the SED way.

Comment: Yes, I've used this method for each upgrade since 16.04 to now, but keep in mind you need to know what you are doing so sometimes depending on installed packages you may run in trouble and may need commands like "sudo dpkg --configure -a" to fix stuff during upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep in mind.